How to make HTML table responsive?
Right now because my table has many columns, right side of table overflows outside of the screen. I want to make it responsive so that the table wraps itself below for more columns. I want the table rows to wrap together as a unit(header and data together). overflow can be observed in this pic
I have looked for solution but the only responsive solution i got was that, add a horizontal scroll bar overflow-x: auto and make it horizontally responsive. But i dont want to apply this.
I was wondering if wrapping was possible with tables.
This is how i want the table to wrap
My code:


body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #231F20;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #000000;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}

.content h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.content table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.content table,
.content th,
.content td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.content th,
.content td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Inquiry Confirmation</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/aquir/aquir1311/aquir131100316/23569861-sample-grunge-red-round-stamp.jpg" alt="Logo" width="200">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <table>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Dep. Date</th>
            <th>Dep. Time</th>
            <th>Aircraft</th>
            <th>From</th>
            <th>To</th>
            <th>PAX</th>
            <th>Tour Type</th>
            <th>Tour Type 2</th>
            <th>Tour Type 3</th>
            <th>Tour Type 4</th>
            <th>Tour Type 5</th>
            <th>Tour Type 6</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>##DATE##</td>
            <td>##TIME##</td>
            <td>##AIRCRAFT_TYPE##</td>
            <td>##FROM##</td>
            <td>##TO##</td>
            <td>##PAX##</td>
            <td>##TourType##</td>
            <td>##TourType 2##</td>
            <td>##TourType 3##</td>
            <td>##TourType 4##</td>
            <td>##TourType 5##</td>
            <td>##TourType 6##</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>




Perhaps an outside-the-box suggestion, but... I wouldn't use a <table> for this output at all.  Instead, I'd create a <div> for each heading/value pair and put those divs into a flex container that wraps.

Thanks, @David for your suggestion to use  elements with flexbox instead of a . I realize now that it's a much more flexible and responsive approach for what I need. I appreciate you thinking outside the box and sharing this idea!

If you decide to follow David's suggestion, I recommend using CSS Grid for a more flexible and responsive layout.
Below is an example of how you can implement a grid layout using CSS:
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  gap: 10px;
}

Example
Demo (with your original code as CSS Grid)
 <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 4</div>
  </div>

  .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
      gap: 10px;
      max-width: 600px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    .grid-item {
      background: #333;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      text-align: center;
    }

